# Permanently configuring LLDB (in Xcode 4.3.2) not to stop on signals

Tags: xcode, macos, signals, lldb

I'm trying to get LLDB (running in Xcode 4.3.2 with an OS X application) to not stop on certain signals. If I enter

`process handle SIGUSR2 -n true -p true -s false`

on the debugging console it works fine and LLDB no longer stops on SIGUSR2.

However, if I put

`command process handle SIGUSR2 -n true -p true -s false`

into ~/.lldbinit it seems to be ignored. Other commands in this file (e.g. alias) work fine.

How can I make LLDB never stop on certain signals?

Comment: I don't think that what you want to do is doable, without an explicit  The process is a run-time concept. Maybe there's a useful setting under "settings list" that you can set?

Comment: Thanks, that explains why adding the command to ~/.lldbinit did not work :)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In case anyone else ever has this question, I finally solved it by adding a breakpoint in `NSApplicationMain()` (for plain C programs, `main()` would of course work as well).

I set the breakpoint action to `process handle SIGUSR2 -n true -p true -s false`, and enabled the "Automatically continue after evaluating" option.

[image: Xcode 4 Breakpoint Screenshot]

If anyone has a more elegant solution, I'd be happy to hear.

Comment: Just in case... Don't forget to change symbol to `UIApplicationMain` for iOS.

Comment: Itworks for me. but after my application freezes. Would this be the true behavior?

Comment: Telling lldb to ignore certain signals should not cause an application to freeze. Where does your application freeze and how?

Comment: For Swift use "UIApplicationMain"

Comment: You might also just ignore the signal with ```signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)```

Comment: Wether you ignore or not the signal will not prevent xcode to stop :( (and btw you should better use sigaction() to ignore a signal)

Comment: @puzzle could you explain or let a link about the `process handle [signal] -n true -p true -s false` line? Just for the sake of understanding what I'm copy/pasting :)

Comment: @itMaxence If you enter `help process handle` in your lldb console, you'll get an explanation of all the possible arguments.

Comment: In Xcode 13, having a commandline tool as target, setting this breakpoint in ìnt main(...) ...`, I get: "error: invalid target, create a target using the 'target create' command". any hints any one?