# iOS SWIFT application - How to ignore SIGPIPE signal globally?

Tags: swift, ios8, signals, sigpipe

I am trying to ignore SIGPIPE signal that is thrown by a third party SDK I am using in my Swift application. 
How do I make my application ignore SIGPIPE signal globally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is the same as in a C program:

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)
```

The problem is that `SIG_IGN` is not defined in Swift. For C programs, it is defined
in `<sys/signal.h>` as

```
#define SIG_IGN     (void (*)(int))1
```

but this integer to pointer conversion is not imported into Swift, so you have
to define it yourself:

```
let SIG_IGN = CFunctionPointer<((Int32) -> Void)>(COpaquePointer(bitPattern: 1))
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)
```

For **Swift 2 (Xcode 7)** the following should work:

```
typealias SigHandler = @convention(c) (Int32) -> Void
let SIG_IGN = unsafeBitCast(COpaquePointer(bitPattern: 1), SigHandler.self)
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)
```

As of **Swift 2.1 (Xcode 7.1),** `SIG_IGN` is defined as a public property 
and you can simply write

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was struggling with swift syntax trying to create CFunctionPointer to represent SIG_IGN. I am testing your solution right now. Thanks again for quick reply!

Comment: I'm struggling on this issue, where exactly do I put the code you provided? I tried it on the entry point on my swift app but I still get the signal :-/

Comment: Never mind me I ended up editing an obj-c file of the lib I'm using as per this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/450130/3104287
Though if you think I must do it your way in swift please let me know :)

Comment: @Martin R do you know how to do this in Swift 2.1? I copied your code but there's an error saying `'CFunctionPointer' is unavailable: use a function type '@convention(c) (T) -> U'. I don't really understand how to convert it to said function, so I'm wondering if you could help me here?

Comment: For swift 2.1, just use signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN) worked for me.

Comment: @MartinR hmm, now `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)` is the first thing executed in `application(_ application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:)` and I still managed to catch the app crashing on SIGPIPE. I'll try some investigation

Comment: @iOSUnit: It seems that the *debugger* (lldb) by default breaks on all signals, compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/12649223/1187415 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/10431579/1187415. – So you can simply "continue" or change the signal handling behavior with `process handle -p true -s false SIGPIPE`

Comment: Hi, for swift 5 is there any new grammar? thanks!

Comment: @ch271828n:  It should still be `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)`  – are the any problems with it in Swift 5?