# handling sigterm in OSx

Tags: c++, macos, signals, sigterm

I have console C++ application built in XCode 6 and want to add SIGTERM handler to it. There are a lot of examples, but I can't get them to work.

```
#include <csignal>

namespace
{
  volatile std::sig_atomic_t gDone = 0;
}

static void term_handler(int i)
{
  gDone = 1;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  std::signal(SIGTERM, term_handler);
  while (!gDone);
  return 0;
}
```

The debugger stopped on the `while` statement, but the handler was not called. The same problem with this code

```
#include <signal.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t gDone = 0;

void term_handler(int i)
{
  gDone = 1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    sigset_t newset;
    sigemptyset(&newset);
    sigaddset(&newset, SIGHUP);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newset, 0);
    sa.sa_handler = term_handler;
    sigaction(SIGTERM, &sa, 0);

  while(!gDone);  
  return 0;
}
```

Is there a problem with the code? What is the right way to handle signals in OSX?

Comment: How are you delivering the signal?

Comment: @jxh by using "kill". the problem is that XCode breaks execution of the cycle and actually shows message that execution was interrupted by SIGTERM. but the handler doesn't get called.

Comment: Can you put the break point on the `return` instead of the `while`? I am not sure what breaking on the `while` buys you.

Comment: @jxh I didn't put any breakpoints there, XCode does that automatically. the only breakpoint placed me is inside the handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'm home now and working on my Mac. Again, your code (second sample specifically) has proven just fine. The confirmation was done in Terminal with gcc and "kill -TERM ". Source refers to SIGTERM, like normal, but kill refers (on OS X) to TERM. The XCode pause you are seeing is due to XCode, not your code. I tried it both ways, Terminal and XCode. I could not find a pref to inhibit that interruption, however.

Just to focus here ...You asked, Is there a problem with the code? Answer: No. You asked, What is the right way to handle signals in OSX? Answer: The way you're already doing it. New question: How do I get XCode (lldb) to not pause when signals occur? Answer: [How to tell LLDB debugger not to handle SIGBUS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984051/how-to-tell-lldb-debugger-not-to-handle-sigbus)

Comment: (un?)fortunately, you are right, when in debugger session the handler won't work, cause debugger intercepts the signals.

Comment: I think you can still do this.  When I looked at "man lldb", I saw mention of 3 files that are read by lldb when launched.  I have used .gdbinit files with gdb to set up breakpoints, etc., saving me manual set up with each and every debug session.  So I'd bet if you tailor the stackoverflow answer referenced above to your SIGTERM, you could put that command in the init file for lldb, and XCode will invoke lldb and behave as you wish.  I think.

Answer (score 2):

After you send the signal, and the debugger stops, you have to continue to get to your breakpoint inside the signal handler.

> ```
> (lldb) break set -n term_handler
> Breakpoint 1: where = a.out`term_handler(int) + 4 at sig.cc:11, address = 0x0000000100000f54
> (lldb) run
> Process 42532 launched: './a.out' (x86_64)
> Process 42532 stopped
> * thread #1: tid = 0x18dc39, 0x0000000100000f30 a.out`main(argc=15, argv=0x00007fff5fbffb58) + 32 at sig.cc:17, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGTERM
>     frame #0: 0x0000000100000f30 a.out`main(argc=15, argv=0x00007fff5fbffb58) + 32 at sig.cc:17
>    14   int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
>    15   {
>    16     std::signal(SIGTERM, term_handler);
> -> 17     while (!gDone);
>    18     std::puts("done!");
>    19     return 0;
>    20   }
> (lldb) c
> Process 42532 resuming
> Process 42532 stopped
> * thread #1: tid = 0x18dc39, 0x0000000100000f54 a.out`term_handler(i=15) + 4 at sig.cc:11, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
>     frame #0: 0x0000000100000f54 a.out`term_handler(i=15) + 4 at sig.cc:11
>    8    
>    9    static void term_handler(int i)
>    10   {
> -> 11     gDone = 1;
>    12   }
>    13   
>    14   int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
> (lldb) `
> ```

Comment: well, I recall I tried to continue and it wouldn't break, but I'll recheck in the morning.

Comment: nothing happens when I press continue, the app continue to run, and the breakpoint inside handler doesn't get hit

Comment: Seeing as I have demonstrated all my steps and shown I cannot reproduce your problem, I cannot help you any further, other than to make sure you are sending the correct signal to your process. `kill -SIGTERM whatever-the-process-id-is`

Comment: well, i'm sure that SIGTERM signal is send, cause I tried both kill versions and XCode actually tells me that execution was broke by SIGTERM. I'm yet to check donjuedo link about lldb

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine.  Kill with:

```
kill -SIGTERM 31573
```

because

```
kill -9 31573
```

where 31573 was my process ID, did not exit gracefully.  I added a printf to your code to tell me it was exiting gracefully.

Comment: Oops.  I did that work on Ubuntu, not the OS X I just noticed.  Now I'm crossing my fingers that the answer works for you, too.

Comment: `kill -9` is not at all equivalent to `kill -SIGTERM`, which is why your process did not exit gracefully with `kill -9`. `SIGKILL`, a.k.a. signal number 9, is not trappable. `SIGTERM` is generally signal 15 on Linux - not sure if OSX orders their signals differently or not...

Comment: OK, I'm home now and working on my Mac.  Again, your code (second sample specifically) has proven just fine.  The confirmation was done in Terminal with gcc and "kill -TERM <pid>".  Source refers to SIGTERM, like normal, but kill refers (on OS X) to TERM.  The XCode pause you are seeing is due to XCode, not your code.  I tried it both ways, Terminal and XCode.  I could not find a pref to inhibit that interruption, however.

Comment: nothing new happens. i get a break on the while operator saying "Thread 1: signal SIGTERM", when I press continue the cycle never breaks and breakpoint in the handler is never hit

Comment: Just to focus here ...You asked, Is there a problem with the code? Answer:  No.  You asked, What is the right way to handle signals in OSX?  Answer:  The way you're already doing it.  New question:  How do I get XCode (lldb) to not pause when signals occur?  Answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984051/how-to-tell-lldb-debugger-not-to-handle-sigbus

Comment: @donjuedo please post that as an answer