# SIGTERM sometimes triggered instead of [NSApp terminate:] when quitting from dock

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm developing an OpenGL 4.1 game engine for Mac in Objective C++ using Cocoa without nib files.  I've discovered that in rare cases (perhaps 1 in 15?), quitting the game by selecting "Quit" in the dock triggers a **SIGTERM** signal and does *not* invoke `terminate:` on NSApplication.  The app disappears from the dock and the app switcher, but the app remains open as an invisible process that has to be terminated from Activity Monitor (the game loop continues to run with no way to interact with the program).

When this occurs, the Xcode debugger breaks on this line in my rendering code:

```objectivec
[[view openGLContext] flushBuffer];
```

**EDIT: It turns out that this can actually occur at any point of execution, but it just most commonly occurs during this call because my game engine spends most of its time waiting for flushBuffer to return. /EDIT**

...with SIGTERM.  'view' is the NSOpenGLView associated with my NSWindow.  No associated error messages appear in the Xcode terminal or in Console.  Clicking continue then puts the process back into the game loop.

Is SIGTERM an expected way for macOS to handle quitting from the dock?  I can't find any online resources that tells me I need a signal handler to deal with valid quit requests.  `NSSupportsSuddenTermination` is off, and I've been unable to identify any other factors which might lead to getting a SIGTERM signal instead of a regular `terminate:` call.  I'm also unclear what relationship this has, if any, to the `flushBuffer` call that is consistently the breakpoint.

EDIT: Here's the main function, with irrelevant engine-specific stuff stripped out:

```c
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        // Create the NSApplication
        [NSApplication sharedApplication];

        // Set up custom app delegate
        MacAppDelegate * delegate = [[MacAppDelegate alloc] init];
        [NSApp setDelegate:delegate];

        // Activate and launch NSApp
        [NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];
        [NSApp setPresentationOptions:NSApplicationPresentationDefault];
        [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
        [NSApp finishLaunching];

        {
            Application app; // Pure C++ class, destructor called when leaving scope

            NSEvent *e;
            do
            {
                while((e = [NSApp nextEventMatchingMask: NSEventMaskAny
                                              untilDate: nil
                                                 inMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                                dequeue: YES]))
                {
                    // Pump messages
                    [NSApp sendEvent: e];
                    [NSApp updateWindows];
                }
            } while (app.Run()); // Returns false when the player has quit
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

EDIT 2: I've confirmed that this issue is unrelated to OpenGL, as I have reproduced this issue with a barebones Cocoa project that doesn't create an OpenGL context.  The project can be downloaded from GitHub here, if anyone wants to try testing it: https://github.com/theOtherMichael/SimpleCppGameLoopForMac

Comment: Could you share your main.m(mm) if it is different than the usual 3 lines

Comment: The file with my main function has got a lot of irrelevant stuff in it, but I'll try to update the question with a concise version of the main function.

Comment: So far unable to recreate the problem with my own small NIBless OpenGL program.

However, on looking at my code I notice that I had to explicitly add the NSOpenGLView to the autorelease pool, which I don't do in my other MacOS/iOS OpenGL programs. View creation is:

    CubeGLView * view = [[[CubeGLView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds] autorelease];

When I took the autorelease out it still worked fine, but this is a very simple program with no complicated destructors. 

So maybe you need to manually add your Cocoa view or other NSObjects to the autorelease pool? Not much, best I can do

Comment: Thanks for the lead, Hugh!  I wasn't explicitly marking the NSOpenGLView to the autorelease pool, but unfortunately after testing I was able to confirm that my issue wasn't as simple as that.  However, I am looking into how I've set up my autorelease pools to determine whether this is an area in which I've overlooked something.  I'm primarily a C++ programmer, and really only am using Objective-C to support Mac.

Comment: I was unaware that I could use Product > Analyze to statically identify potential memory leaks in my Objective-C code, which helped me track down a number of cases where I mishandled autorelease.  However, after resolving all of them, I've confirmed I still periodically encounter the issue.

Comment: @theOtherMichael did you ever track this down? I'm having a similar issue, except it occurs 100% of the time. I've configured an event handler for kAEQuitApplication but it simply does not get called and I get the SIGTERM instead

Answer (score 0):

I think I've worked out some of what is going on here. I'm encountering a similar issue, though in my case it occurs almost 95% of the time when trying to quit from the dock

It seems the debugger is halting on SIGTERM before the kAEQuitApplication handler has a chance to be handled. This feels a very much like a race condition in Cocoa, and I suspect that something in NIB land handles this gracefully (and perhaps also inhibits the debugger from breaking on SIGTRAP in this scenario)

I've had a modicum of success with the following steps:

1. Install a custom signal handler, something like

```
static void sigTermHandler (int signum)
{
    // Trap the signal, tell the application to shutdown
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"SIGTERM handler called async on main thread.");
        [application terminate:nil];
    });

}

// Wherever your entry point is
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // Set the signal handler
    if (signal(SIGTERM,  sigTermHandler) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        // error
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

2. When you start your debug session, you'll need to tell Xcode not to trap on SIGTERM.  You can do that by setting a breakpoint and issuing the following in the console:

```
(lldb) pro hand -p true -s false SIGTERM
NAME         PASS   STOP   NOTIFY
===========  =====  =====  ======
SIGTERM      true   false  true
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984051/how-to-tell-lldb-debugger-not-to-handle-sigbus) for more info on that one (the comments there describe other ways to do this, eg: adding a breakpoint action)

This is all quite nasty though, and you run the risk that the race condition still persists - you may end up with a clean run where shutdown occurs *and* this signal handler then also tried to perform shutdown, so you may need to guard for that (in fact, most definitely)

I'm not terribly satisfied with this, but it's all I've managed to work out so far and it at least ensures proper shutdown outside of a debugger (and only minor inconvenience within the debugger)

UPDATE: I'm tired and didn't think to just disable the kAEQuitApplication handler and rely solely on the SIGTERM handler, this avoids any race condition that might exist otherwise.