# Swift on macOS: Running code on termination of background app

Tags: swift, macos, kill-process, sigint, sigterm

I am writing a Mac app that runs as a daemon in the background. How can I detect when the app is killed and run some cleanup code? I have tried catching signals such as `SIGTERM`, `SIGINT`, and `SIGKILL`, but my app structure seems to have some problems with this.

This is the basic flow of my application start from the main thread:

```
func signalHandler(signal: Int32) { ... }

let signals = [SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGKILL]
for sig in signals {
    signal(sig, signalHandler)
}

// code to kick off background execution that will occasionally need to run some stuff on the main thread

RunLoop.current.run() // SIGTERM shows up in Xcode on this line, signalHandler not called
```

If I stop the app using Xcode's stop button or force quit from the Activity Monitor, the app just exits with exit code 9 (`SIGKILL`). If I choose "Quit" from the activity monitor, the app receives a `SIGTERM` but the handler doesn't get called... Xcode just highlights the `RunLoop` line and says `Thread 1: signal SIGTERM`.

Without the `RunLoop` line my application will stop almost immediately but I need to keep it alive. At the same time, I am thinking perhaps that line is blocking the main thread and preventing the signal handler from being run. Are there any ways around this so I can handle my app termination gracefully?

Answer (score 3):

A couple of notes:

- `SIGKILL` [cannot be caught](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908694/sigkill-signal-handler).
- if the debugger is attached, it will intercept the signal handlers instead of letting the flowing through the program; a workaround to this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42639333/1974224)

Try printing the signal and launching the program from the command line

```swift
func signalHandler(signal: Int32) {
    print("Caught signal \(signal)")
}
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> prints `Caught signal 2`

Terminating the process from Activity Monitor via `Quit` (not `Force Quit`) prints `Caught signal 15`

Comment: Are you able to add more detail on how/why lldb interferes with the signal handlers? Is there a way to run with lldb still but have it not interfere? I'm hoping to write some unit tests for signal handling which would require lldb.

Comment: @sschilli [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42639333/1974224) might give more insight.