# How do you create a LLDB script to ignore SIGSEGV and SIGBUS

Tags: matlab, lldb

I frequently run matlab in lldb to debug some shared libraries and would like to make a lldb script so rather than typing out the following two lines.

`process handle --pass true --stop false --notify true SIGSEGV
process handle --pass true --stop false --notify true SIGBUS`

I could create a file at ~/.lldb/ignore_sigs
but im not sure what to put in that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way "process handle" works, you have to have a running process to attach the signal behaviors to; it doesn't adhere to the target.  So you will need to do this once you have a process.  The easiest way to do that is to set a breakpoint on main in your .lldbinit file, and add the commands to that breakpoint:

```
break set -n main -C "process handle..." -C "process handle..."
```

Breakpoints set in the .lldbinit file get inherited by all lldb debugging sessions.  If you only want this to apply to your matlab debugging sessions, you could make a Python command that checks the name of your target executable and only does the `process handle` if it is matlab, and then runs the process handle commands.  You could then call that Python command from the breakpoint as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a file in **~/.lldb/ignoreSigs.py**

with the following content

```
import lldb

def ignoreSigs(debugger, command, result, dict):
    debugger.HandleCommand("process handle --pass true --stop false --notify true SIGSEGV")
    debugger.HandleCommand("process handle --pass true --stop false --notify true SIGBUS")

def __lldb_init_module (debugger, dict):
  debugger.HandleCommand('command script add -f ignoreSigs.ignoreSigs ignoreSigs')
```

Then I added the following line to **~/.lldbinit**

```
comma script import ~/.lldb/ignoreSigs.py
```

After launching matlab I am able to disable signals via

```
matlab -Dlldb
run 
#Wait for first signal to occur.
ignoreSigs
```

Comment: You can actually pass multiple signal names to the same `process handle` command. So for example, you can use just `process handle --pass true --stop false --notify true SIGSEGV SIGBUS` and even add more at the end. Run this command in the lldb console to see more info: `help process handle`

Comment: You can also just omit the signal name entirely to apply to all signals if you want that behavior. Though I'm not sure it'll work in a script since it prompts asking if you are sure (and setting it in a breakpoint in Xcode didn't work for me, but running it manually did).

Answer (score 0):

Jim Ingham's approach worked for me, the only downside was that the breakpoint  in `main` got hit multiple times in different functions, e.g. when iOS app got  in the background. I added `-o true` and now it hits only once:

`break set -n main -o true -C "process handle --stop false --notify false SIGUSR1 SIGUSR2"`

Got it from lldb's help:

`lldb`

`help breakpoint set`

```
-o <boolean> ( --one-shot <boolean> )
       The breakpoint is deleted the first time it stop causes a stop.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to configure lldb with a script so that there won't be a need to enter any commands manually.

Find a script in the other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70312647/147805