# When debugging, can I make Xcode ignore certain signal?

Tags: xcode, macos, signals

I am making some development on Xcode for a OS X application. I need to send SIGUSR1 to the application by:

```
  kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1)
```

This worked. However, each time the SIGUSR1 sent, Xcode was blocked to show me that a signal was caught. Can I make Xcode simply ignore this signal and keep continous running during debugging?

Thank you at advance!

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing shamelessly from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431579/permanently-configuring-lldb-in-xcode-4-3-2-not-to-stop-on-signals) you can use something like

```
process handle SIGUSR1 -n true -p true -s false
```

from the LLDB console.  The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10456557/2431627) to that question has a method for enabling this automatically on every run.