# Xcode LLDB: HowTo not stop but pass signals

Tags: xcode, lldb

**Question:** How can I configure / tell Xcode's LLDB to not stop on - and pass a certain singal for a Commandline Tool?

---

**Background:**

We are using 3rd party code that relies on SIGUSR1.

Running in Xcode 13, LLDB stops on that signal and eats it (i.e. does not pass it).

Our targtet is a command-line tool, not an NSApplication.

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10456557/1457385) to a very similar question (only difference AFAICS is that it is a NSApplication). It says to use this command:

```
process handle SIGUSR1 -n true -p true -s false
```

in a Symbolic Breakpoint, setting `main()` as symbol.

But that gives us:

> error: invalid target, create a target using the 'target create' command

---

I have tried with a "normal" breakpoint in main():

[image]

And with a Symbolic Breakpoint, using `main()` as symbol:

[image]

Both breakpoints log the described error, so that proves:

- the breakpoint does work
- the command is processed but causes the error

The Xcode scheme used is setup for `debug` and the correct executable:

[image]

---

When using the command in LLDB - console (instead of Xcode), it works fine, so the command seems to be OK.

---

**HowTo Simple Reproduce:**

- In Xcode, "new Project" -> "Comman Line Tool"
- Name it "TestLLDB" and save anywhere
- set breakpoint in `main()` line 13 (NSLog...)
- Edit the the breakpoint and add "Debugger Command" Action: "process handle SIGUSR1 -n true -p true -s false"
- Run the project
- check the console for the above error

Comment: You can't call "process handle" until you have an actual process.  That's why the answer you quote says to put the "process handle" command into a breakpoint command on main, at that point there will be a running process.  But from the error, it sounds like you don't even have a target yet (created with the 'file' - i.e. 'target create' - command).  But I'd have to see a complete session to tell in more detail what's going on.

Comment: @JimIngham: re "put the "process handle" command into a breakpoint command on main, at that point there will be a running process": that is exactly what I am doing (as written in the question. Sorry for being mistakable). I _do_ put the command in a breakpoint. And that gives me the error. Using LLDB in command line it works fine.

Comment: Can you put your exact breakpoint command in the question?  The "invalid target" error doesn't make sense if you are in a breakpoint command, where you obviously have a target or you couldn't hit the breakpoint...

Comment: @JimIngham I agree that it doesn't make sense, that's why I am asking here desperately :-) . Thanks for having a look, I have updated the question with imgs of the used breakpooints.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce the behavior you report.  I followed your steps and the process handle command works correctly.  Probably time to file a bug with a copy of your project.  Since this is Xcode related, it's best to report to http://bugreporter.apple.com.

Comment: @JimIngham I am on Xcode 13.0. What version r u using? (will file a bug when still occurring with latest Xcode but r curious). Thx again, really appreciate.

Comment: Also Xcode 13.0